# UserWarning: The `lr` argument is deprecated, use `learning_rate`

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to train a neural network with textgenrnn but when I run the code it immediately gives me a warning `UserWarning: The lr argument is deprecated, use learning_rate`

How can I fix this "problem"?

CODE

```
from textgenrnn import textgenrnn

textgen = textgenrnn()
textgen.train_from_file('my_file.txt', num_epochs=1)
textgen.generate()
```

WARNING

```
/Users/username/Documents/Develop/Neural2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:375: UserWarning: The `lr` argument is deprecated, use `learning_rate` instead.
  warnings.warn(
2021-08-04 00:34:58.301349: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
76 texts collected.
Training on 1,374 character sequences.
2021-08-04 00:34:58.861705: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:176] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a problem with the package using old parameter names. It's just a warning, so the code will still run normally.

The warning will go away when the package gets updated.

In the meantime, to ignore the warning run the file with the -W flag.

`python -W ignore::DeprecationWarning file.py`

Or import the warnings module and catch the warning in the code.

```
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    textgen = textgenrnn()
    textgen.train_from_file('my_file.txt', num_epochs=1)
    textgen.generate()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply
Yes, everything works without problems
I just wanted to know if there was a way to fix it while waiting for the library update

Comment: @Piero I updated the answer to show how to remove the warning.